# Definition of output C_00 and C_002 in FeynCalc

Tags: feyncalc

When I am using FeynCalc, I am getting an output as follows:

> ```
> Subscript[C, 00](0,Overscript[p, _]^2,Overscript[p, _]^2,0,0,0)
> ```
>
> and
>
> ```
>  Subscript[C, 002](0,Overscript[p, _]^2,Overscript[p, _]^2,0,0,0)
> ```

Could you please help me to find the "definition" of `C₀₀` and `C₀₀₂` in terms of the 4-dimensional integration in momentum space?

Answer (score 2):

This is a Passarino-Veltman coefficient function, that appears when doing tensor decomposition of 1-loop integrals, see e.g. [hep-ph/0509141](https://arxiv.org/pdf/hep-ph/0509141.pdf)

Often (especially for singular kinematics) one can define it only as a Feynman parameter integral. FeynCalc uses the same conventions as LoopTools, c.f. the [LoopTools manual](http://www.feynarts.de/looptools/LT28Guide.pdf).

For complicated kinematics, numerical evaluation is usually the only sensible way to arrive to compact results. Analytic results can be obtained e.g. with [Package-X](http://packagex.hepforge.org/). My add-on [FeynHelpers](https://github.com/FeynCalc/feynhelpers) allows to access Package-X from FeynCalc

[image]